# Using concatenation operator in knockout data binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, string-concatenation

I am trying to add a string to the id attribute of an element using '+' operator. But the id could not be generated. Below is the code snippet:

```
  <section data-bind="foreach: tabs">
    <article  data-bind="attr: { id: 'tab' + ($index() + 1) }">

    </article>
  </section>
```

Above html is in a html file which is rendered using ko.renderTemplate method.

Comment: What do you mean the id could not be generated? Do you get some errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, the error thrown is unexpected identifier

Comment: There's got to be more than that, here is [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fftae7a3/1/) with your script.

Comment: There's something else wrong with your code (which is difficult to diagnose seeing it).  I tried your HTML with a simple view model of: ko.applyBindings({
    tabs: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
}); and it worked fine.

Comment: When using ko.renderTemplate,there was an error. So, I solved the problem by sending the id parameter in tabs object instead of concatenating in the template.

Answer (score 1):

another solution I found, is using String.concat

```
<article  data-bind="attr: { id: 'tab'.concat($index() + 1) }">
```

tested working in KnockoutJS 3.4.2